# manipulate data in vuejs and post it in input field

Tags: php, vue.js

I am having a simple input of a number and want to echo out it´s data manipulated in an disabled input field.

```
<input type='number' v-model='dm'> //this is the user input
<input type='number' disabled> //dmtoeur(dm)

methods: {
dmtoeur: function(val) {
     return (Math.round(((val/1.95583) + 0.00001)*100)/100);
}
}
```

in the second input field there schould be the value of the first one calculated with the function dmtoeur.

For example:

- 1st input: 1
- second (disabled) input field: 1.96

This **has** to be on an .php file.

Comment: `:value='dmtoeur(dm)'`

Answer (score 0):

Here's a working example. Might be a bit overkill, but I only had few minutes to write the code :)

```js
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    dm: 1,
    dmtoeur: 0.51,
  },
  methods: {
    calculateDmToEur: function() {
      this.dmtoeur = (Math.round(((this.dm / 1.95583) + 0.00001) * 100) / 100);
    },
  },
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.5.17/dist/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <input type='number' v-model='dm' @click="calculateDmToEur()" @keyup="calculateDmToEur()">
  <input type='number' v-model='dmtoeur'>
</div>
```